# Bypass .htaccess authorization for registration page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use a .htaccess rule to add an extra layer of password security to the wordpress login page. Now as the whole `wp-admin` is protected. Users who wish to register, lands on the page with the `username` and `password` prompt for the `authentication`.

Is there anyway I can bypass this only for user registration URI?

I currently have `authentication` for this URL - `www.example.net/wp-login.php`

But I couldn't exclude the `authentication` prompt for this URL - `www.example.net/wp-login.php?action=register`

**This is my .htaccess rule:**

```
<FilesMatch "wp-login.php">
AuthName "Authorized Users only"
AuthType Basic    
AuthUserFile /home/user/.wpadmin    
require valid-user  
</FilesMatch>
```

Is there anyway to exclude the security `authentication` for the queried URL for registering in my site?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly (not tested) but you'll need a rewrite rule to create a specific URL for the registration page eg.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule wp-register wp-login.php?action=register  [NC,L]
```

Then a block to disable authentication for that URL eg:

```
<Location "wp-register">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from All
  Satisfy Any
  #AuthBasicFake dummyRegOnlyUserId dummyRegOnlyPass
</Location>
```

If that doesn't work as is, try adding a *dummyRegOnlyUserId* to your password file and uncommenting the directive.